# How to get rid of this warning?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf

I'm using jsf with bootstrap to deal with my front-end project. Inside some xhtml file, I got to use a navbar component from bootstrap. I have this line of code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
```

And with this I got the following warning:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Undefined attribute name (class).
- Unknown tag (nav).
```

Although this works on browser, I have no idea on how to remove this warning.

Comment: Have you included the HTML namespace in your XHTML? `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Comment: Bad title... And does it not result in this error if you don't use twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: I have included the HTML namespace before. Thanks for the try Jasper de Vries. Kukeltje, my goal is to use bootstrap without this warning, so using bootstrap is a must.